# Calling private API with python

Tags: python, api

I am fairly new to API, Si I followed some tutorials and posts here but I am having issues calling an API using client ID and secret, the API uses bearer token for authentication, I cant get authenticated properly. Here is what I am using:

```
import base64
import requests

client_id = "abcd123"
client_secret = "EFGH456"

authorization = base64.b64encode(bytes(client_id + ":" + client_secret, "ISO-8859-1")).decode("ascii")

headers = {
"Authorization": f"Basic {authorization}",
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
body = {
"grant_type": "client_credentials"
}

response = requests.post("https://mywebsite/api/", data=body, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

I am not sure how to get and store the bearer token and what is the problem with the code I am using.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prepend `Bearer` to the authorization header value, not `Basic`. I'm assuming that you've properly encoded your token.

```py
headers = {
"Authorization": f"Bearer {authorization}",
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
```

Check out [this article](https://community.mega.com/t5/REST-API/Basic-Auth-vs-Bearer-Token/td-p/23476) for an explanation of the difference.

Comment: Thank you Michael, but now I am getting the following error
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."

Comment: This error means that you can't use the POST method, it has nothing to do with authorization. Please provide the API documentation, otherwise it will be very difficult to help you further.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael for your reply, I dont have the documentation and I have requested it from the company last week and still waiting to get it, I thought there could be a solution out there with the help of the community here that could save me some time. but thank you so much

Comment: Yeah, we could stab at it blindly, but it's much better to have the docs.

Comment: Hello Michael, I got a response from the company who developed the API and they said they dont have anyone who can write python and they dont have documentation, the only info that I got from them was that I should use Auth2 and bearer token to authenticate, and the endpoints names. I know I am asking for much but would you be able to help me please?

Comment: I'd love to help, but working with an undocumented API is like brute forcing a password. Firstly, you mention "Auth2," is that actually "OAuth2?" Next, I will make a best-effort attempt to figure out the authorization if you provide details on how I may access the API. Do not provide your token or any secrets, just provide the URL(s) and info on how you obtained your token.